# Trying to delete a file using Node.js. Should I use asynchronously fs.unlink(path, callback) or synchronous fs.unlinkSync(path)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple function which deletes a product entry from the database, and now I'm trying to delete the image file of that product as well. I checked the Node.js file system docs and found 2 functions which deal with that - `fs.unlink(path, callback)` and `fs.unlinkSync(path)`. I understand that the first one is asynchronous and that the second one is synchronous, but I'm still not quite sure which one should I use and why.

```
module.exports.deleteProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    let productId = req.body.productId

    try {
        let product = await Product.destroy({
            where: {
                id: productId
            }
        })

        res.status(200).json({
            product: product
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500)
    }
}
```

Comment: Always use async. Synchronous functions are only appropriate in single-user scripting.

Comment: What's the context? How is the code being invoked? (i.e. which larger process is this a part of?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code and an idea for you:

As others have already said, `async` is better than `sync`, so you won't end up blocking, even though, unless your API volume is extremely high, it probably won't matter, as indicated in another answer.

You can use the fs `promises` API via

```
const fs = require('fs').promises; //es5 OR
import { promises as fs } from 'fs'; //es6
```

to use the async (non-blocking) API with a one-liner `await`.

Special note: you **may** not want your API request to fail if you failed to unlink the directory, as you did in fact delete the product from the database.

```
// make sure you are using the promise API from fs
const fs = require('fs').promises;

module.exports.deleteProduct = async (req, res, next) => {
    let productId = req.body.productId

    try {
        let product = await Product.destroy({
            where: {
                id: productId
            }
        })

        try { 
            await fs.unlink('the/path/to/the/product/image');
        } catch {
          // you may want to handle a failure to delete separately
        }

        res.status(200).json({product: product})
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500)
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh it's great that I can use await on the fs.unlink!. Just out of curiosity, if I don't surround the await fs.unlink with try-catch block in my current code, I'd send a 500 status if the unlink fails for whatever reason even though the product deletion will go through, correct?

Comment: @Bobimaru - you got it exactly right. That's why I suggested you might want to handle any resultant errors from `unlink` separately.

Comment: Hey, I just got to trying out the async/await fs.unlink and I actually got an error stating - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined. I assume this is because, I haven't supplied a callback as a secondary parameter to the unlink function, but I thought I wouldn't need it when using async/await.

Comment: @Bobimaru - Please make sure you are using `require('fs').promises` and not just `require('fs')` - or if you are using es6 `import { promises as fs } from 'fs'`

Answer (score 1):

If your server OS is Linux or some other UNIX derivative with a local file system, both `.unlinkSync()` and `.unlink()` run quickly: the OS-level unlinking operation is designed to complete quickly and predictably. So, if you use the blocking `.unlinkSync()` version you won't do much harm, especially if your unlinking is infrequent.

That being said, if you can use the asynchronous version it's a good practice to do so.

It looks like you can; you can call `res.status()...` from within a callback or after an `await`.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't Block the event loop in Node Js

The synchronous methods blocks the `event loop` unnecessarily ,which affects your application performance .always use `async` methods ,wherever possible.

or if you want to use it with `await`operation (pseudo sync) ,you can do something like below ,by wrapping it within `promise`

```
const fs=require("fs");
function unlinkPromise(file)
{

  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    fs.unlink(file,(err,data)=>{
      
      if(err)
      {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    })
  })
}

async function data()
{
  console.log(await unlinkPromise("file"));
}
```

Comment: [fs has a built in promise module accessible by `require('fs').promises`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

Comment: Umm yeah ,that will work too .It was just a suggestion for OP if we wants to use the original callback styled method.